Firebase - flutterfire configure not working (Timeout Exception)
I am working on connecting my new Flutter project with Firebase. I have successfully executed the 'firebase login' and 'dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli' commands. However, I am facing an issue while running the 'flutterfire configure' command. It keeps showing a timeout exception every time I try to run it. I need some help to resolve this error.
This is what it shows after running flutterfire configure
TimeoutException after 0:00:15.000000: Future not completed
I have already tried firebase logout, firebase login to relogin and also tried firebase login --reauth commands as well. And also a deferent internet connection too.
Furthermore, this is not my first flutter app to try Firebase. I already had two Flutter projects connected to Firebase (I have deleted one to confirm that there is no limitation issue), and broth worked really well. This is my third app to try.

It's not clear what's causing the problem, but I wonder if retrieving the list of projects is failing. If so, you can try passing the project ID on the command line with flutterfire configure --project <your project id>.

Yeah, the problem was failing to retrieve the project list and this project Id passing method worked. (I am not sure how but I already tried this method several times and it did not worked at the time)

Hey @Prashan. Since passing the proiject ID ont he command line works, can you accept my answer below (so that I can close other questions against this one): https://stackoverflow.com/a/78466246/209103?

Go to your firebase project, then after click your firestore database, then after tap on rule tab and change date and time to access this database data.
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 1, 25); // change this date according to your need.


Neither the firebase login command nor the flutterfire configure command that OP runs interacts in any way with their Firestore database. There is no way for their security rules to cause this problem.

If retrieving the list of projects is failing, you can try passing the project ID on the command line with:
flutterfire configure --project <your project id>


For me, even when --project <project_id> is specified, It still tries to fetch available firebase projects and fails with the same error. Is there a way to manually configure?

@LahiruChandima I'm experiencing this as well. Passing the --project flag does nothing, Flutterfire still tries to fetch all projects.

I had timeout issues as well and unexpectedly solved it by switching internet connection.
I know that the question states that this was tried, but I feel like I won't be the only person where this will be a viable solution.
Therefore I wanted to add this as an answer here: Try to switch your internet connection.

I encountered the same issue on Windows 11 and resolved it with the following steps:

Created a new Firebase App to avoid potential configuration corruption.

Restarted the computer.

Ran the following commands in PowerShell inside my Flutter App directory:


dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
flutterfire configure --project=<project_id>

Ensure to replace <project_id> with your actual project ID.
Note: The flutterfire command only worked when executed in PowerShell. It did not function properly in the VSCode terminal. After following these steps, the issue was resolved.

I had exactly the same issue and installing Node.js fixed it.
Command to install Node.js on my local machine:
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.40.0/install.sh | bash

Update your terminal with source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh.
Now, you're able to install the Firebase CLI tool:
npm install -g firebase-tools

and able to run the flutterfire configure without any issue.
Hope it helps!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
